# Draw VectorDrawable XML over Canvas Android

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view

I am having Custom-view & I am trying to draw Vector Image (starttask.xml), which is under res/drawable/starttask.xml  , I am not able to find perfect way to do it

Comment: Code please....

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I'll answer it anyway, it may help someone.

Use the method Resources.getDrawable, to get a Drawable object, then render it with the draw method, and then use the method Drawable.setBounds to define the position and size of the drawable. Its something like this:

```
Drawable drawable = getResouces().getDrawable(R.drawable.xml_vector, null);
drawable.setBounds(...);
drawable.draw(canvasObj);
```

Comment: `setBounds(0, 0, width, height)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/dcc0db651e7443f247c0e9c9a40acc5a) code to create a `Shape` from your VectorDrawable, then use `Shape.draw(Canvas,Paint)` to use it on your canvas.